# reading Chinese csvfile in python

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to read a csv file with the following code but it still can't print Chinese

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv ('weibo_status.csv') status = df[1:]
#print (df.head)
```

I think this might be the problem that the characters are in a data frame, because the following code works fine in my system  (python 2.7, editor: pycharm)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import jieba

seg_list = jieba.cut("我来到北京清华大学", cut_all=True) print("Full Mode: " + "/ ".join(seg_list))
```

weibo_status.csv

```
userid     status
1          我今天吃饭了
2          吃了水果
3          今天感冒了
```

Comment: It would be helpful for people to answer your question if you mentioned your python version (2 or 3)

Comment: do you have to use python2? I believe it may work on python 3, because python3 uses utf8 (which supports Chinese) as default.

Comment: If you have to use python2, you have to use different encodings for "reading" the file and "writing" the file. I don't know well about chinese encoding, but check if your "writing" setting is correct as well. For example, if you are printing to the terminal and if terminal's default encoding is not supporting Chinese, then you may see broken characters even if your reading was done correctly.

Comment: And note that this is very system dependent question, so it may also be helpful to specify 1. Your OS, 2. Your IDE/Editor 3. Your terminal (and version too, if available)

Comment: + also an example CSV file would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the df directly and you may get the dataframe.
You may try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('weibo_results.csv',encoding='utf-8'))  
print df['userid']
#or may be you can print to see the entire dataFrame like This (uncomment below)
#print df
```

This should be fine with your version of python.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I should convert the csv file to utf-8 before I read it with python